# How to get the attributes of an added item in DynamoDB using Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have an `AWS Lambda` function which is being triggered by `AWS DynamoDB`. The function checks if the operation in the DB is `INSERT`, and if it does, then it sends a new push message using `AWS SNS`:

```
console.log('Loading function');

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');  
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {  
    console.log("\n\nLoading handler\n\n");
    var sns = new AWS.SNS();

    console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    event.Records.forEach(function(record) {
        if (record.eventName == "INSERT") {
            sns.publish({
                Subject: 'Test',
                Message: 'Test publish to SNS from Lambda',
                TopicArn: 'TOPIC-ARN'
            }, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err.stack);
                    return;
                }
                console.log('push sent');
                console.log(data);
                context.done(null, 'Function Finished!');  
            });
        }
    });
    callback(null, "message");
};
```

Is there a way that I could get the attributes of the newly added item?

Comment: That info should be on the `event` object. I see you are logging the `event` object, do you not see the data there?

Comment: So, according to the sample data, `record.dynamodb.Keys.Id` is supposed to be 101?

Comment: I'm sorry but your question makes no sense. How would we know what your updated record's `Id` value should be?

Answer (score -1):

```
var id = record.dynamodb.Keys.Id.N;
```